# Executing operations one after the other

Tags: swift, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I am struggeling with something and I would like to ask you if you could point me in the right direction.

I have four tasks I want to complete, -one after the other.

1. Fetch html-code from web
2. Parse this code and save to core data storage
3. Use this data and batch save to calendar
4. Upload the parsed data to my own web server.

I have written all the code for this and it executes fine. However, at times it struggles as some of the code is executed before the other has finished.

Example:

```
func startProcess () {

    fetchHTMLFromWeb()

    parseHTML()

    saveToCalendar()

    //Sometimes uploadToWeb() starts before saveToCalendar() is finished
    uploadToWeb()

}
```

I have tried reading up on GCD, but it is a rather complex subject and I am finding it hard to grasp it.

Can you recommend any good readups on this subject?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the problem? 
When you finish to fetch the html Code Just call the parser withe te fetched datas.
It didn't works?

Comment: That's what I want to accomplish, but how can I make it so that the next code is only executed when the previous has completed? I'm thinking callback functions is the way to go, but that is unknown territory for me.

Comment: why not call parseHTML() in the fetchHTMLFromWeb() function?
And call startProcess in a background thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the GCD to execute all your stuffs in the background queue.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  self.startProcess();
});
```

with that, startProcess will start on the background queue/thread. So you can

In the `fetchHtmlFromWeb` method just call `parseHtml()`, when the fetch is ended.
hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into that. Seems like the right way to go.